# Alert Dialog on selection of particular drop down item

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have made a `Spinner` of city selection. I have some particular cities shown there (specified in my project) and the last item in the `dropDownList` is "others". I want that when the users select "others", either a dialog comes with a `TextInputLayout` asking for the user to type in the city, or in any other way. I just want that after selecting others, I ask the user to enter the city and that city is shown on the spinner field. I am new to Android Studio and can't seem to solve the condition.

Here is what I have done so far. 
spinner layout in my `activity_main.xml`

```java
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/citySpinner"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

Layout for styling the selected text shown in the spinner field

```java
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_bold"
    android:textColor="@color/Blue"
    android:textSize="16sp">
</TextView>
```

Layout for the drop down items

```java
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/Blue"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium">
</TextView>
```

and My main activity

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner citySpinner = findViewById(R.id.citySpinner);
        List<String> cityList = new ArrayList<String>();
        cityList.add("Select a City");
        cityList.add("Banglore");
        cityList.add("Pune");
        cityList.add("Mumbai");
        cityList.add("Noida/Ghaziabad");
        cityList.add("Other");

        ArrayAdapter<String> cityDataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        R.layout.city_spinner_selected_item, cityList);  
        cityDataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_
        spinner_dropdown_item);
        cityDataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.register_dropd
        own_item);
        citySpinner.setAdapter(cityDataAdapter);

}
```

Now, how do I set an alert dialog on others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an `OnItemSelectedListener` and with `position == 5` you know, when *others* is clicked.

```
citySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(position == 5){
        //show your dialog
    }
}

});
```

Then you create a dialog with an `EditText`.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
alert.setTitle("Enter City");

EditText editText = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(editText);


alert.setPositiveButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
       //Here you set the text of your EditText to your TextView
       yourtextview.setText(editText.getText().toString());
    }
});

alert.show();
```

Then you just put it in your `OnItemSelectedListener`.

```
 citySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(position == 5){


AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alert.setTitle("Enter City");

    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(editText);


    alert.setPositiveButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
           //Here you set the text of your EditText to your TextView
           yourtextview.setText(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    alert.show();
    }
    }

    });
```

Comment: What is yourtextview here? Because I wanted to show the entered city in the spinner selected item.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the entered text instead of "others"?

Comment: yes. Whatever city name is entered after clicking on "others" that name is displayed. Can it be done?

Comment: @RohanVaish Yes, you can try to remove the last item (“others“) of your list and add the new text. Then you set your adapter again.